# Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed on ubuntu

Tags: csv, ubuntu, neo4j, load

I'm trying to import a csv file in NEO4j db using script :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///dataframe6.txt" AS line
RETURN count(*)
```

But I get following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/home/gaurav/sharing/dataframe6.txt
```

P.S. : I'm using ubuntu machine

added this line dbms.directories.import=/home/gaurav/sharing/

and    dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

Comment: Well, it looks like it knows where to go, so lets check the obvious ... can you do a ls -l /home/gaurav/sharing/dataframe6.txt and check if the neo4j user (that runs the database if your using the apt install) can read that file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change folder permission for user NEO4j, it works now

Comment: How you changed folder permissions for user Ne14j?